# How do bronzed villains in warehouse 13 avoid becoming totally insane?

Tags: warehouse-13

It is established that bronzed villains are still conscious and experience the time they are bronzed.
Most bronzed villains we see on screen are in this state 100 years or more.

While one could argue that those villains are already mad and insane even before bronzing, I think it is surprising that they aren't completely insane babbling idiots when they become debronzed in the end. Being an evil genius who want's to control or destroy the world does not automatically protect from going insane after 100 years of locked in live I think.

Examples:

H.G. seems to be more or less sane after debronzing.

The alchemist behaves like if he awakes after a good long sleep.

EDIT:

It seems there is no answer and my assumptions are not so broadly accepted as I thought, so I will close this.
Ok, deleting an answered question seems not to be the good way here. I think the answer is wrong, so what should I do with this question? Delete it anyway?

Comment: In the real world people with [Locked-in Syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locked-in_syndrome) don't seem to go insane.

Comment: In the real world people with Locked-in Syndrome do not live 100 or more years. And they are stimulated and cared by their families (mostly I think) and so on.

Comment: Erm. Any guesses about the downvotings? I have no idea what I did wrong with my question.

Comment: It seems very opinion-based. It also starts with an assumption.

Comment: Really? So I seem to be the only one who thinks that is is a fact (and not my humble opinion) that expierience 100 years as an immobile statue in a dark room who is seldom visited by someone should drive one mad? And who wonders why the guy who is debronzed after (weren't it even 500 yrs?) behaves like awakening in the morning? Ok. Then I have to adjust my mindset and check if other things I take as a matter of course are also just my "opinions". :-)

Comment: Since no-one has actually spent a hundred years in isolation, it's hard to tell what the actual effects would be. What little experimentation there has been would tend to suggest that long exposure would result in near-continual hallucinations (but no lasting mental affects in the long-term) rather than actual madness; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensory_deprivation#.22Total_Isolation.22

Comment: While I agree it does not start with an assumption (HG and the Alchemist both talk about remaining aware), I do not think this is really "opinion based."  I would be surprised if there is not an answer somewhere within the show.

Comment: [Belgian Man Trapped In Coma For 23 Years Was Conscious Throughout](http://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/171937.php?trendmd-shared=1) "_Houben said he just spent the time dreaming of a better life. ... 
He told his doctors that sometimes he was only his consciousness and "nothing else" as he travelled with his thoughts into the past or "into another existence"._"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only answer given (with the Escher vault) is wrong.
To "terminate" the question I respond it myself.

It seems that there are real world examples of people who where locked in fully conscious for over 20 years without going insane. So the assumptions of my question are wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In universe

IIRC bronzed individuals were kept in the Escher vault and time and space doesnt behave in the Escher vault so 100 years could seem like 1 day or maybe 1 month (if debronzed characters talk about the years in isolation etc it could be hyperbole)

out of universe

some people can enter a form of hibernation where brain activity is greatly decreased and one hour of waking thoughts could consume a week or more actual time

Comment: Afaik they are kept in the bronze sector. Not in the Escher vault. The Escher vault is the thing with the ever moving stairs and gravity upside down where only people like Mrs. Frederic seem to be able to enter and don't get lost. The bronze sector is entered in several episodes by all the main characters, without passing the weird stair thing.